# CTRL + A to select a whole file name doesn't work for icons on the desktop

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, file-extension

I want to rename a file with its extension using CTLR + A to select whole name, but it doesn't work on the desktop.

I'm using WIN7, and this process just doesn't work when a file is on my desktop.

Comment: "but it doesn't work on the desktop" what happens instead? Does it work if your file isn't on the desktop?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Nothing happens, just try.

Comment: @MátéJuhász it doesn't select all the name, and if the file be in some place else it work.

Comment: I press F2 to select filename and then I have to use ctrl+Home then ctrl+Shift+end to select filename with it's extension. but because my end key is broken. I have to press shift and then use right arrow to select filename with it's extension

Comment: "my end key is broken" most keyboards have 2 "end" keys ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> when you have the filename.

It's not the same function as the "select all", but it will select the whole filename with extension in two cases: when you enter the field for editing and when your cursor is at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I would do this but the problem is, I don't have a mouse right now and the end key on my keyboard is broken so I couldn't use this function

Comment: @ArashRabiee If it's a broken keyboard problem, you can remap the key (even make the whole sequence on one press) using AutoHotKey.

Comment: I used AutoHotKey and is working, thanks. But do you think is it possible to somehow make CTRL + A function work properly to rename a file on desktop.

Comment: So far it's a mystery. It just doesn't work as in other cases.

Comment: @ArashRabiee "I used AutoHotKey and is working, thanks" I mean the method to changing the function to remap the end key worked,

Answer (score 1):

#### This process just doesn't work when a file is on my desktop

> I want to rename a file with its extension using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to select whole name, but it doesn't work on the desktop.

It works if you open your desktop using explorer:

1. Type <kbd>[image]</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>
2. Select "Desktop"
3. Select the file
4. Type <kbd>f2</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>
5. The whole file name is selected (including the extension).

Comment: yes, ctrl + a works when I using explorer to open my desktop. So is this a bug or just my win7 has this problem?

Comment: @ArashRabiee I have the same problem. Appears to be a bug.